# neural network doesn't learn at all for a simple problem

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm getting into deep learning so I'm reading 'Neural Networks and Deep Learning' by Michael Nielson. I've downloaded his first neural network and tried it on a dataset and it worked properly. Then I wanted to try and make my own data to see if I understood how data is given to the neural network. This is my code for creating data:

```
import numpy as np


def function(x):
    """ If the first value of the row matrix is 1 the output will be 1,
    if zero, the output will be zero"""
    if x[0, 0] == 1:
        y = np.array([[1]])
    else:
        y = np.array([[0]])
    return y


def data_maker(data_size, split_ratio):
    """ Data size is the size of the data and the split ratio
     is the ratio between testing data and training data. """

    # make random lists of 3 by 1 numpy arrays consisting of zeros and ones.
    training_inputs = [np.random.randint(0, high=2, size=(3, 1)) 
                       for _ in range(int(split_ratio * data_size))]
    testing_inputs = [np.random.randint(0, high=2, size=(3, 1)) 
                      for _ in range(int((1 - split_ratio) * data_size))]

    training_outputs = [function(x) for x in training_inputs]
    testing_outputs = [function(x) for x in testing_inputs]

    training_data = list(zip(training_inputs, training_outputs))
    testing_data = list(zip(testing_inputs, testing_outputs))
    return training_data, testing_data
```

I then tried to train the neural network on the created data but then a problem arose. For some reason the amount of good predicted testing examples doesn't seem to go up nor down. It looks like this:

```
import function_data_maker
training_data, test_data = function_data_maker.data_maker(100000, 0.8)

import First_NN
net = First_NN.Network([3, 5, 1])
net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

The output I got is as follows:

```
Epoch 0: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 1: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 2: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 3: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 4: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 5: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 6: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 7: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 8: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 9: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 10: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 11: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 12: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 13: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 14: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 15: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 16: 9973 / 19999
Epoch 17: 9973 / 19999
...
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the way I feed the data to the neural network or what else is wrong?
Please help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: the learning rate looks to be too high, and it is a good idea to normalize values

Comment: @Marat Changing the learning rate doesn't seem to make any difference. The inputs I give to the neural network are already between 0 and 1 so what is there to normalize?

Comment: typical learning rate is 0.01..0.05, anything higher than 1 is nonsense. Normalizing means bringing mean to 0 and variance to 1. Values in [0, 1] have mean of 0.5. Try generating -1 or 1 instead. The reason why it is important is simple but a bit too long to explain in a comment

Comment: @Marat, I changed it so that the input value are only 1 or -1. I still get the same problem.